# Need regex to get the version from this output

Tags: regex

Kindly assist me with a regex for the following:

```
TEXT : /xxx/xxx/xxx/xxxx/abc_2.77.789.46836936_xxxx/xxxx/xxxxxxx
```

I need a regex to extract the number after `abc_` and before the last period (`.`). Except for the numbers others are constant.

Expected result: `2.77.789`

Comment: Please share 1) the environment you are using the regex in, 2) your current regex + code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
abc_([\d.]+)\.
```

Result in 1st Capturing Group $1

https://regex101.com/r/1JIops/1